# How to test the type of a generic interface?

Tags: delphi, generics

I'm not sure if the title makes sense, but I hope you can understand my question with some code.

Given the following code for a publish/subscribe framework.

```
type
  IMessage = interface
    ['{B1794F44-F6EE-4E7B-849A-995F05897E1C}']
  end;

  ISubscriber = interface
    ['{D655967E-90C6-4613-92C5-1E5B53619EE0}']
  end;

  ISubscriberOf<T: IMessage> = interface(ISubscriber)
    procedure Consume(const message: T);
  end;

  TMessageService = class
  private
    FSubscribers: TList<ISubscriber>;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure SendMessage(const message: IMessage);
    procedure Subscribe(const Subscriber: ISubscriber);
    procedure Unsubscribe(const Subscriber: ISubscriber);
  end;
```

That would be used like this:

```
TMyMessage = class(TInterfacedObject, IMessage);

TMySubscriber = class(TInterfacedObject, ISubscriberOf<TMyMessage>)
  procedure Consume(const Message: TMyMessage);
end;

TMyOtherMessage = class(TInterfacedObject, IMessage);

TMyOtherSubscriber = class(TInterfacedObject, ISubscriberOf<TMyOtherMessage>)
  procedure Consume(const Message: TOtherMessage);
end;
```

How can I loop the subscribers list and send the message to the proper subscribers?

The subscribers list will have all subscribers for all types of messages. The SendMessage have to find the subscribers for the type of message provided as param and send it to whom implements the proper interface to consume that type of message.

```
  procedure TMessageService.SendMessage(const message: IMessage);
  var
    Subscriber: ISubscriber;
  begin
    for Subscriber in FSubscribers do
    begin
      // How to send the message only to the subscribers of the correspondent type of message
    end;
  end;
```

Thanks!

BTW, this code is based on this [blog post](http://www.finalbuilder.com/Resources/Blogs/tabid/458/EntryId/278/The-quest-for-the-perfect-publish-subscribe-mechanism-in-Delphi.aspx).

Comment: It's difficult to know what your problem is and what you mean by "the proper subscriber". It's hard to find the motivation to read the blog post you link to. If you were to summarise in as concise a manner as possible then you may be more help.

Comment: Thanks @David, I've added more information to try to explain more what I want.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to have `TMessageService.SendMessage` send the message to every subscriber and let the subscriber's `Consume` method decide whether to process it or ignore it?

Comment: @codeelegance maybe easier, but a bad implementation IMHO. If the same object subscribe to several messages, it would be a big if or case statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit**: found a way to make this less convoluted (please vote on this answer as you like this; it took quite a while to get it right).
Note it uses the new `Rtti` unit, so it works **only** for Delphi 2010 and up (I used Delphi XE for developing this, I did not yet verify this in Delphi 2010).

For the `Supports`, you need to store some *[IID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_ID#Technical_details)* GUIDs *with your interfaces and a means to query them*.
Since you want to use this with generics, you want to able to query the IID GUID from an interface type, not from an interface reference (as [Hallvard Vassbotn showed with a hack in 2006](http://hallvards.blogspot.com/2006/09/hack11-get-guid-of-interface-reference.html)).
The new [RTTI](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/RTTI) introduced in Delphi 2010 allows you to do just that:

```
unit RttiUnit;

interface

type
  TRtti = record
    //1 similar to http://hallvards.blogspot.com/2006/09/hack11-get-guid-of-interface-reference.html but for the interface type, not for a reference
    class function GetInterfaceIID<T: IInterface>(var IID: TGUID): Boolean; static;
  end;

implementation

uses
  TypInfo,
  Rtti;

class function TRtti.GetInterfaceIID<T>(var IID: TGUID): Boolean;
var
  TypeInfoOfT: PTypeInfo;
  RttiContext: TRttiContext;
  RttiInterfaceType: TRttiInterfaceType;
  RttiType: TRttiType;
begin
  TypeInfoOfT := TypeInfo(T);
  RttiContext := TRttiContext.Create();

  RttiType := RttiContext.GetType(TypeInfoOfT);
  if RttiType is TRttiInterfaceType then
  begin
    RttiInterfaceType := RttiType as TRttiInterfaceType;
    IID := RttiInterfaceType.GUID;
    Result := True;
  end
  else
    Result := False;
end;

end.
```

So now the changed code, which I rearranged a bit, and spread over more units to keep the overview.

**ClassicMessageSubscriberUnit**: has the non generic interfaces `IMessage` and `ISubscriber` (they descend from `IImplementedWithClass` which makes it easier to log things.

```
unit ClassicMessageSubscriberUnit;

interface

type
  IImplementedWithClass = interface(IInterface)
    function ToString: string;
  end;

  IMessage = interface(IImplementedWithClass)
    ['{B1794F44-F6EE-4E7B-849A-995F05897E1C}']
  end;

  ISubscriber = interface(IImplementedWithClass)
    ['{D655967E-90C6-4613-92C5-1E5B53619EE0}']
  end;

implementation

end.
```

**GenericSubscriberOfUnit**: contains the generic `ISubscriberOf` interface which descends from the generic `ISupporterOf` and a generic base implementation called `TSupporterOf`:

```
unit GenericSubscriberOfUnit;

interface

uses
  ClassicMessageSubscriberUnit;

type
  ISupporterOf<T: IMessage> = interface(ISubscriber)
    ['{0905B3EB-B17E-4AD2-98E2-16F05D19484C}']
    function Supports(const Message: T): Boolean;
  end;

  ISubscriberOf<T: IMessage> = interface(ISupporterOf<T>)
    ['{6FD82B1D-61C6-4572-BA7D-D70DA9A73285}']
    procedure Consume(const Message: T);
  end;

type
  TSupporterOf<T: IMessage> = class(TInterfacedObject, ISubscriber, ISupporterOf<T>)
    function Supports(const Message: T): Boolean;
  end;

implementation

uses
  SysUtils,
  RttiUnit;

function TSupporterOf<T>.Supports(const Message: T): Boolean;
var
  IID: TGUID;
begin
  if TRtti.GetInterfaceIID<T>(IID) then
    Result := SysUtils.Supports(Message, IID)
  else
    Result := False;
end;

end.
```

**MessageServiceUnit**: now only contains `TMessageService`, some type aliases and some actual code for managing the list so I could actually test it.

```
unit MessageServiceUnit;

interface

uses
  Generics.Collections,
  ClassicMessageSubscriberUnit,
  GenericSubscriberOfUnit;

type
  ISubscriberOfIMessage = ISubscriberOf<IMessage>;
  TListISubscriber = TList<ISubscriber>;

  TMessageService = class
  private
    FSubscribers: TListISubscriber;
  strict protected
    procedure Consume(const SubscriberOf: ISubscriberOfIMessage; const Message: IMessage); virtual;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure SendMessage(const Message: IMessage);
    procedure Subscribe(const Subscriber: ISubscriber);
    procedure Unsubscribe(const Subscriber: ISubscriber);
  end;

implementation

uses
  SysUtils;

constructor TMessageService.Create;
begin
  inherited Create();
  FSubscribers := TListISubscriber.Create();
end;

destructor TMessageService.Destroy;
begin
  FreeAndNil(FSubscribers);
  inherited Destroy();
end;

procedure TMessageService.SendMessage(const Message: IMessage);
var
  LocalMessage: IMessage;
  lSubscriber: ISubscriber;
  lSubscriberOf: ISubscriberOf<IMessage>;
begin
  for lSubscriber in FSubscribers do
  begin
    LocalMessage := Message; // to prevent premature freeing of Message
    if Supports(lSubscriber, ISubscriberOf<IMessage>, lSubscriberOf) then
      if lSubscriberOf.Supports(LocalMessage) then
        Consume(lSubscriberOf, LocalMessage);
  end;
end;

procedure TMessageService.Subscribe(const Subscriber: ISubscriber);
begin
  FSubscribers.Add(Subscriber);
end;

procedure TMessageService.Unsubscribe(const Subscriber: ISubscriber);
begin
  FSubscribers.Remove(Subscriber);
end;

procedure TMessageService.Consume(const SubscriberOf: ISubscriberOfIMessage; const Message: IMessage);
begin
  SubscriberOf.Consume(Message);
end;

end.
```

Finally a unit that I used to test everything (it uses the bo-library at http://bo.codeplex.com):

```
unit GenericPublishSubscribeMainFormUnit;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, LoggerInterfaceUnit, MessageServiceUnit,
  MessageSubscribersUnit, ClassicMessageSubscriberUnit;

type
  TGenericPublishSubscribeMainForm = class(TForm)
    TestPublisherButton: TButton;
    LogMemo: TMemo;
    procedure TestPublisherButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
  strict private
    FLogger: ILogger;
  strict protected
    function GetLogger: ILogger;
    property Logger: ILogger read GetLogger;
  public
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

type
  TLoggingMessageService = class(TMessageService)
  strict private
    FLogger: ILogger;
  strict protected
    procedure Consume(const SubscriberOf: ISubscriberOfIMessage; const Message: IMessage); override;
  public
    constructor Create(const Logger: ILogger);
    property Logger: ILogger read FLogger;
  end;

var
  GenericPublishSubscribeMainForm: TGenericPublishSubscribeMainForm;

implementation

uses
  LoggerUnit,
  OutputDebugViewLoggerUnit,
  LoggersUnit,
  MessagesUnit;

{$R *.dfm}

destructor TGenericPublishSubscribeMainForm.Destroy;
begin
  inherited Destroy;
  FLogger := nil;
end;

function TGenericPublishSubscribeMainForm.GetLogger: ILogger;
begin
  if not Assigned(FLogger) then
    FLogger :=  TTeeLogger.Create([
      TOutputDebugViewLogger.Create(),
      TStringsLogger.Create(LogMemo.Lines)
    ]);
  Result := FLogger;
end;

procedure TGenericPublishSubscribeMainForm.TestPublisherButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  LoggingMessageService: TLoggingMessageService;
begin
  LoggingMessageService := TLoggingMessageService.Create(Logger);
  try
    LoggingMessageService.Subscribe(TMySubscriber.Create() as ISubscriber);
    LoggingMessageService.Subscribe(TMyOtherSubscriber.Create() as ISubscriber);
    LoggingMessageService.SendMessage(TMyMessage.Create());
    LoggingMessageService.SendMessage(TMyOtherMessage.Create());
  finally
    LoggingMessageService.Free;
  end;
end;

constructor TLoggingMessageService.Create(const Logger: ILogger);
begin
  inherited Create();
  FLogger := Logger;
end;

procedure TLoggingMessageService.Consume(const SubscriberOf: ISubscriberOfIMessage; const Message: IMessage);
var
  MessageImplementedWithClass: IImplementedWithClass;
  MessageString: string;
  SubscribeImplementedWithClass: IImplementedWithClass;
  SubscriberOfString: string;
begin
  SubscribeImplementedWithClass := SubscriberOf;
  MessageImplementedWithClass := Message;
  SubscriberOfString := SubscribeImplementedWithClass.ToString;
  MessageString := MessageImplementedWithClass.ToString; // wrong VMT here, Delphi XE SP2
  Logger.Log('Consume(SubscriberOf: %s, Message:%s);',
    [SubscriberOfString, MessageString]);
//    [SubscriberOf.ClassType.ClassName, Message.ClassType.ClassName]);
  inherited Consume(SubscriberOf, Message);
end;

end.
```

--jeroen

Old solution:

<strike>This might do it, but I still find the solution a bit convoluted.</strike>

**MessageServiceUnit**: `ISubscriberOf` now has a `GUID` and a `Supports` method to check if the `IMessage` is in fact supported.

```
unit MessageServiceUnit;

interface

uses
  Generics.Collections;

type
  IMessage = interface(IInterface)
    ['{B1794F44-F6EE-4E7B-849A-995F05897E1C}']
  end;

  ISubscriber = interface(IInterface)
    ['{D655967E-90C6-4613-92C5-1E5B53619EE0}']
  end;

  ISubscriberOf<T: IMessage> = interface(ISubscriber)
    ['{6FD82B1D-61C6-4572-BA7D-D70DA9A73285}']
    procedure Consume(const Message: T);
    function Supports(const Message: T): Boolean;
  end;

  TMessageService = class
  private
    FSubscribers: TList<ISubscriber>;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure SendMessage(const Message: IMessage);
    procedure Subscribe(const Subscriber: ISubscriber);
    procedure Unsubscribe(const Subscriber: ISubscriber);
  end;

implementation

uses
  SysUtils;

constructor TMessageService.Create;
begin
  inherited Create();
end;

destructor TMessageService.Destroy;
begin
  inherited Destroy();
end;

procedure TMessageService.SendMessage(const Message: IMessage);
var
  lSubscriber: ISubscriber;
  lSubscriberOf: ISubscriberOf<IMessage>;
begin
  for lSubscriber in FSubscribers do
  begin
    if Supports(lSubscriber, ISubscriberOf<IMessage>, lSubscriberOf) then
      if lSubscriberOf.Supports(Message) then
        lSubscriberOf.Consume(Message);
  end;
end;

procedure TMessageService.Subscribe(const Subscriber: ISubscriber);
begin
  FSubscribers.Add(Subscriber);
end;

procedure TMessageService.Unsubscribe(const Subscriber: ISubscriber);
begin
  FSubscribers.Remove(Subscriber);
end;

end.
```

**MessagesUnit**: Messages each have an `interface` with a `GUID` so `Supports` can check for the `GUID`.

```
unit MessagesUnit;

interface

uses
  MessageServiceUnit;

type
  IMyMessage = interface(IMessage)
    ['{84B42EC8-CAC0-44B4-97A8-05AE5B636236}']
  end;
  TMyMessage = class(TInterfacedObject, IMessage, IMyMessage);

  IMyOtherMessage = interface(IMessage)
    ['{AB323765-FF7B-4852-91AA-B7ECC1845B41}']
  end;
  TMyOtherMessage = class(TInterfacedObject, IMessage, IMyOtherMessage);

implementation

end.
```

**MessageSubscribersUnit**: all subscribers have a `Supports` method checking the right `GUID`.

```
unit MessageSubscribersUnit;

interface

uses
  MessagesUnit, MessageServiceUnit;

type
  TMySubscriber = class(TInterfacedObject, ISubscriberOf<IMyMessage>)
    procedure Consume(const Message: IMyMessage);
    function Supports(const Message: IMyMessage): Boolean;
  end;

  TMyOtherSubscriber = class(TInterfacedObject, ISubscriberOf<IMyOtherMessage>)
    procedure Consume(const Message: IMyOtherMessage);
    function Supports(const Message: IMyOtherMessage): Boolean;
  end;

implementation

uses
  SysUtils;

procedure TMySubscriber.Consume(const Message: IMyMessage);
begin
  //
end;

function TMySubscriber.Supports(const Message: IMyMessage): Boolean;
begin
  Result := SysUtils.Supports(Message,  IMyMessage);
end;

procedure TMyOtherSubscriber.Consume(const Message: IMyOtherMessage);
begin
  //
end;

function TMyOtherSubscriber.Supports(const Message: IMyOtherMessage): Boolean;
begin
  Result := SysUtils.Supports(Message,  IMyOtherMessage);
end;

end.
```

**MessagesUnit**: contains the specific messages (both the interface and class types), which contain the IID GUIDs to distinguish them with `Supports`.

```
unit MessagesUnit;

interface

uses
  MessageServiceUnit,
  ClassicMessageSubscriberUnit;

type
  IMyMessage = interface(IMessage)
    ['{84B42EC8-CAC0-44B4-97A8-05AE5B636236}']
  end;
  TMyMessage = class(TInterfacedObject, IMessage, IMyMessage);

  IMyOtherMessage = interface(IMessage)
    ['{AB323765-FF7B-4852-91AA-B7ECC1845B41}']
  end;
  TMyOtherMessage = class(TInterfacedObject, IMessage, IMyOtherMessage);

implementation

end.
```

**MessageSubscribersUnit**: contains the specific subscribers (both the interface and class types), which now do not need the `Supports` method any more: they only contain the `Consume` method.

```
unit MessageSubscribersUnit;

interface

uses
  MessagesUnit,
  MessageServiceUnit,
  GenericSubscriberOfUnit,
  ClassicMessageSubscriberUnit;

type
  TMySubscriber = class(TSupporterOf<IMyMessage>, ISubscriber, ISubscriberOf<IMyMessage>)
    procedure Consume(const Message: IMyMessage);
  end;

  TMyOtherSubscriber = class(TSupporterOf<IMyOtherMessage>, ISubscriber, ISubscriberOf<IMyOtherMessage>)
    procedure Consume(const Message: IMyOtherMessage);
  end;

implementation

uses
  SysUtils;

procedure TMySubscriber.Consume(const Message: IMyMessage);
begin
  //
end;

procedure TMyOtherSubscriber.Consume(const Message: IMyOtherMessage);
begin
  //
end;

end.
```

--jeroen

Comment: That did it, thanks! I was hoping to have a way to avoid two methods and an interface per message, but I think it's not possible.